# CrystalReport becomes empty when adding certain column

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

I have this CrystalReport, this report shows data from 4 data tables 
the tables are, Products, Order, Invoice and Customer
My problem is that the reports shows all data that i add, but not Customer columns.

And when i try to add any column from customer to the report, the report becoms empty and nothing appears.

I have created a Dataset as a datasource and im sure that the data set is filled by the data.

Here my code that fills the data set

```
public ActionResult Report(int CustmId, int OrderId)
    {

        DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
        ds.EnforceConstraints = false;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ENTERPRISE-PC;Initial Catalog=Fakturor;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        String query = "select * From Customer where id= "+CustmId+"";
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        adapter.Fill(ds,"Customer");

        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from Products v JOIN OrderVaror ov on v.id = ov.IdVara where ov.IdOrder = "+OrderId+"", con);
        adapter.Fill(ds,"Products ");

        adapter =  new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from [Order] where id ="+OrderId+"",con);
        adapter.Fill(ds, "Order");


        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select id, Datum, Price, PaymentDay, moms from Invoice", con);
         adapter.Fill(ds, "Invoice");

        con.Close();



            ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
            rd.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Repport/CrystalReport1.rpt")));
            rd.SetDataSource(ds);

            Response.Buffer = false;
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.ClearHeaders();


            try
            {
                Stream stream = rd.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
               // return View("ViewPage1");
               return File(stream, "application/pdf", "EverestList.pdf");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
    }
```

Comment: When this kind of problem happened with me, it was a empty foreing key.

Comment: @NickeDaSilvaManarin how did you solve it

Comment: Look at your DataSet, seek for empty tables, If, in the report, you try to access that table, nothing will show up (just the lines and textfields), so the only way i got to work with was filling the empty tables with dummy data.